# Applying a t-test to a polling a result

Tags: t-test

I am trying to analyze a poll result for two different message treatments (`T1` and `T2`) that essentially asks "Was this message helpful?" and there are two responses, "Yes", and "No" (but should be noted that not all survey get a response).  We want to see which message tests better with subjects.

Someone suggested using a [t-test](https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/t-test/) to compare the number of positive responses.  But I'm confused as to how to apply the t-test given that the "mean" of all the positive responses is always 1.  The difference between the two populations would be the number of positive responses.

One thought I had was to say a "No" was equal to `0` and and "Yes" was equal to `1` and then I could calculate a mean of the two populations.  But then what wouldn't be clear is what to do with surveys that didn't get a response

Ultimately I'm trying to understand if the `T1` and `T2` messages yield statistically different distributions to the poll

Comment: What questions do you have about the poll responses?

Comment: I'm trying to understand if the two message treatments yield statistically different distributions of yes's/no's/no responses.  I've expanded upon this a bit in my question

Comment: Check out the chi-squared test or Fisher’s exact test. You’re essentially checking if two dice are weighted the same.

Comment: Wouldn't that require that I know the expected distribution of both populations and would compare if the observed distribution matched the expected?

Comment: You can treat it like comparing if two dice have the same weighting (not if two dice are fair, which is a related but different problem). Chi-squared and Fisher tests are appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 210 Yes's and 183 No's for T1 and 382 Yes's and 205 No's for T2, then you could say that's 210 Yes's out of 393 responses for T1 and 382 Yes's out of 587 responses for T2. In R, a `prop.test` can test whether the rate of Yes's out of responses is the same for T1 and T2 (for details of a similar test see [this page](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm#:%7E:text=Given%20a%20set%20of%20N,proportions%20is%20equal%20to%200).):

```
prop.test(c(210,382), c(293,587), cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(210, 382) out of c(293, 587)
X-squared = 3.8618, df = 1, p-value = 0.0494
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.00154269 0.13037119
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.7167235 0.6507666
```

(Because of the large sample sizes, I suppressed continuity correction.)
The difference between T1 and T2 is barely significant at the 5% level.

If you worry that non-responses might be 'polite' No's (or otherwise of interest), then you could compare numbers of Yes's out of *total surveys* in each group (`prop.test` not shown).

If you want to know if results Yes, No, and NR are homogeneous
across T1 and T2, then you could do a chi-squared test on a $2 \times 3$ table, as follows:

```
t1 = c(210, 183, 47);  t2 = c(382, 205, 60)
TBL = rbind(t1, t2);  TBL
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
t1  210  183   47
t2  382  205   60
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 13.884, df = 2, p-value = 0.0009664

chisq.test(TBL)$resi
        [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
t1 -1.914206  2.070177  0.5604064
t2  1.578567 -1.707190 -0.4621439
```

The null hypothesis of homogeneity is strongly rejected.

The
chi-squared statistic $Q = 13.885$ is the sum of six 'contributions'
$C_{ij} = \frac{(X_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}},$ where $X_{ij}$ are observed counts from `TBL`and $E_{ij}$ are computed from row and column totals of `TBL` using the null hypothesis. Residuals are square roots of $C_{ij}$ with signs depending on the sign of the numerator before squaring.
The residuals with largest absolute values may point the way to useful *ad hoc* tests.

While the non-responses contribute to the overall significance (in my hypothetical data), they do not seem to be candidates for *ad hoc* tests.

Following, @Dave's Comments, you could use chi-squared tests or Fisher exact tests on $2 \times 2$ tables, instead of either `prop.test`.

Comment: 1. On the first link, what are the six syntaxes? They represent a generic language, not R? 2. The extra information from the chi-squared test is helpful to answer the question, as it uses all the data. If I was reporting these results I would be tempted to put that first and then the proportion test below if that was of particular a priori interest. Does using both entail multiplicity issues, not only are the tests using the same data their significance results are going to be “correlated” in a sense.

Comment: The NIST link shows (at least approximately) what `prop.test` does. //  For my hypothetical (simulated) data, `prop.test` barely rejects at the 5% level, so you might not want to use `prop.test` as an _ad hoc_ follow-up to results of `chisq.test`, which rejects at a smaller level of significance. Your concern about possible false discovery is on target. However, this is a question that should be answered for _your actual_ data. My simulated data are introduced so I can show R syntax and output, not to recommend an analysis plan for your data.

Comment: 1. I realised from your resonse and the link that you were referencing this for the formulae, rather than the syntax below this and the formulae are helpful to see what is approximately done. 2. Apologies for this, I was reading the hypothetical values as occurred variates! Nonetheless, these values and R result output helped to think about the question. I would still be inclined to report as per my previous comment, this having been decided at the outset. Thanks for clarification, regarding false discovery.